# Need help turning rows in columns using python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, data-wrangling

I have a dataset that currently looks like this:

```
 FCST/BUD/ACT   Vendor  Act GL  Acct    Manager Amount
 FCST          Walmart   962.0  56340.0 Kunal  1234567
 FCST          Walmart   962.0  56340.0 Kunal  1234567
 ACT           Walmart   962.0  56340.0 Kunal  1234567
 ACT           Kohls    962.0   56340.0 Kunal   1234567
 FCST          TJ      4521.0   56340.0 Labeeb  1234567
 BUD           TJ     4521.0    56340.0 Labeeb 1234567
```

I need to make the  FCST/BUD/ACT in their own separate columns I want the data to look like this

```
               Vendor   Act GL  Acct    Manager FCST    BUD   ACT
                Walmart   962.0 56340.0 Kunal  5555     5555
                Walmart   962.0 56340.0 Kunal  567      3200
               Walmart   962.0  56340.0 Kunal  1234     500       6160
               Kohls    962.0   56340.0 Kunal  2354     321   569
               TJ      4521.0   56340.0 Labeeb  1234567
               TJ     4521.0    56340.0 Labeeb 1234567
```

I have tried:

```
data_teams=pd.pivot_table(data,index=['Act GL','Vendor','Acct','SLT +1','Teams','Account'],columns='FCST/BUD/ACT',values=['total year Amount'],fill_value='0').reset_index()
```

But this does not work as it does not give me all the vendor names(random blank spaces) since some of the values are repeated for different managers. Also since I need the data for tableau, Pivot table format is not ideal. Any other ways to do this other than pivot table?

Comment: can you add a command to generate the original dataframe

Comment: Btw, where do you the get the value `5555` in the first row's `FCST` column?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `groupby` and `unstack` is the best option here:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': ['one', 'one', 'three', 'two', 'two',
                           'four'],
                   'bar': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'baz': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'zoo': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'w', 't']})

col = 'foo'
value_col = 'baz'
level = len(df.columns) - 2
use_cols = [i for i in df.columns if i not in [col, value_col]]+[col]
_df = df.groupby(use_cols)[value_col].agg(lambda x:x).unstack(level=level).reset_index()
_df.columns.name = ''
```

*input:*

```
     foo bar  baz zoo
0    one   A    1   x
1    one   B    2   y
2  three   C    3   z
3    two   A    4   q
4    two   B    5   w
5   four   C    6   t
```

*output:*

```
  bar zoo  four  one  three  two
0   A   q   NaN  NaN    NaN  4.0
1   A   x   NaN  1.0    NaN  NaN
2   B   w   NaN  NaN    NaN  5.0
3   B   y   NaN  2.0    NaN  NaN
4   C   t   6.0  NaN    NaN  NaN
5   C   z   NaN  NaN    3.0  NaN
```

Do a `fillna` as you please.

Answer (score 0):

@Partha Mandal uses groupby and unstack to perform the analysis.  Here is another way, using pivot_table:

First, create the data frame.  The reset_index() function creates a column of sequential integers, so we'll get one row of output for each row of input.

```
columns = ['FCST/BUD/ACT', 'Vendor', 'Act', 'GL', 'Acct_Manager', 'Amount']

data = [
    ('FCST', 'Walmart', 962.0, 56340.0, 'Kunal', 1234567), 
    ('FCST', 'Walmart', 962.0, 56340.0, 'Kunal', 1234567), 
    ('ACT', 'Walmart', 962.0, 56340.0, 'Kunal', 1234567), 
    ('ACT', 'Kohls', 962.0, 56340.0, 'Kunal', 1234567), 
    ('FCST', 'TJ', 4521.0, 56340.0, 'Labeeb', 1234567), 
    ('BUD', 'TJ', 4521.0, 56340.0, 'Labeeb', 1234567)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns).reset_index()
```

Second, call pivot_table(), and drop the index (integer) column we created in the previous step.  Also modify the name of the column index.

```
df_new = df.pivot_table(index=['index', 'Vendor', 'Act', 'GL', 'Acct_Manager'],
                        columns='FCST/BUD/ACT',
                        values='Amount',
                        aggfunc='sum',
                        fill_value=0
                       ).reset_index().drop(columns='index')

df_new.columns.name = ''
```

Finally, show the results, based on the data in the original post:

```
print(df_new)

    Vendor     Act       GL Acct_Manager      ACT      BUD     FCST
0  Walmart   962.0  56340.0        Kunal        0        0  1234567
1  Walmart   962.0  56340.0        Kunal        0        0  1234567
2  Walmart   962.0  56340.0        Kunal  1234567        0        0
3    Kohls   962.0  56340.0        Kunal  1234567        0        0
4       TJ  4521.0  56340.0       Labeeb        0        0  1234567
5       TJ  4521.0  56340.0       Labeeb        0  1234567        0
```